# Undefined 'this' when handing class method to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, binding

I have API methods for my React app within an API class:

```
class API { 

  constructor() {
    //setup axios
  }

  async deleteEquipment(item) {
      return this.axios.delete(...paths and stuff..)
  }
}

export default API(config)
```

This works fine for most of my code, except when I need to hand it to components through the props, like so:

```
import API from '../path/to/api.js'

.. code

<PageTable
  deleteItem={API.deleteEquipment}
  ...more props
/>
```

This doesn't work as it seems `this` used in the class to reference axios is now undefined.

`this.axios` leads to `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'axios')`

I have tried late binding, to bind the method to the class like so:

```
<PageTable
  ...more props
  deleteItem={API.deleteEquipment.bind(API)}
/>
```

but it doesn't seem to have much effect. Any ideas how to keep the `this` reference to the class when the method is called by `PageTable` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want the bind in your API constructor,  `this.deleteEquipment = this.deleteEquipment.bind(this)`,

Comment: @Keith - Genius! That's the one!

Answer (score 0):

try to bind deleteEquipment in constructor

```
this.deleteEquipment = this.deleteEquipment(this);
```

also use await with async functions